# Pass parameters to a function through a link HREF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a function in the HomeController class. Its signature is the following:

```
public ActionResult ChangeCulture(string lang, string returnUrl)
```

So from a partial shared view I am trying to call this function and passing its parameters by doing the following:

```
<a href="/Home/ChangeCulture/\"es-ES\"?this.Request.RawUrl" class="flag"><img src="~/images/SpanishFlag.png"/></a>
```

but it does not work. I want to pass first parameter "es-ES" and second parameter that is `this.Request.RawUrl` to the function.

how to do this?

I do not want to use and `Html.ActionLink`

Comment: Have you tried `Url.Action`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470197%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang = "es-ES", returnUrl = 
this.Request.RawUrl })" class="flag"><img src="~/images/SpanishFlag.png"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Need to pass the parameters with their corresponding name attribute, unless you have a route setup for this:

parameters:

```
@Html.Raw("<a href=\"/Home/ChangeCulture/?lang=es-ES&returnUrl=" + Request.RawUrl.ToString() + "\" class=\"flag\"><img src=\"~/images/SpanishFlag.png\"/></a>");
```

Route (in RouteConfig):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "myRouteName",
    url: "Home/ChangeCulture/{lang}/{url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ChangeCulture", lang = "", url="" }
);
```

which would require a link such as:

```
/Home/ChangeCulture/es-ES/www.xyz.com/abc
```

With a route such as this i'd URL encode the url part at least.